# Why are clouds like Pinata are used to host NFTs rather just using IPFS desktop?

Tags: nft, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ipfs

I have been working on some NFT projects and came across `Pinata` to upload files to IPFS. But there is also `IPFS desktop` that provides the same functionality and is free. So why do people use Pinata cloud for the same job when IPFS desktop is available and is free? Any answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPFS is decentralized only when someone/some service will pin our data. When you run your node/your desktop application it is only pinned to your end and when it will off nobody will be able to get the file. For that reason, our files need at least one node to run every time so the user can fetch the files.

There are many ways you can pin the data:

1. You can run your own node.
2. Run your networks of nodes (and an infrastructure team to manage it)
3. Pay a pinning service to pin your content on their nodes (like Pinata).
4. And/or hope your content becomes so popular that other nodes start pinning it.

Hope it clears your queries!